# How to use data from form to get data from api?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a form in react where I'm asking for the last 8 of the VIN of a car.  Once I get that info, I want to use it to get all the locations of the car.  How do I do this? I want to call the action and then display the results.

Added reducer and actions...

Here is what I have so far...

```
class TaglocaByVIN extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
            searchvin: ''
    }
this.handleFormSubmit=this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
this.changeText=this.changeText.bind(this);

}
handleFormSubmit(e){
e.preventDefault();
let searchvin=this.state.searchvin;
//I want to maybe call the action and then display results
}

changeText(e){
this.setState({
    searchvin: e.target.value
})
}

render(){
return (
        <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
    <label>Please provide the last 8 characters of VIN: </label>
    <input type="text" name="searchvin" value={this.state.searchvin} 
onChange={this.changeText}/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>


        </div>
        );
}
  }
 export default TaglocaByVIN;
```

Here are my actions:

```
export function taglocationsHaveError(bool) {
return {
    type: 'TAGLOCATIONS_HAVE_ERROR',
    hasError: bool
};
 }

 export function taglocationsAreLoading(bool) {
  return {
    type: 'TAGLOCATIONS_ARE_LOADING',
    isLoading: bool
 };
 }

export function taglocationsFetchDataSuccess(items) {
return {
    type: 'TAGLOCATIONS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
    items
  };
}

export function tagformsubmit(data){
return(dispatch) =>{
    axios.get(`http://***`+data)
    .then((response) => {
        dispatch(taglocationsFetchDataSuccess);

    })
  };
}
```

reducer:

```
export function tagformsubmit(state=[], action){
switch (action.type){
case 'GET_TAG_FORM_TYPE':
    return action.taglocations;

    default:
        return state;
}
```

}

Comment: assuming you have a db set up...are you using graphql to query your db or a RESTful api? also, looking at your react-redux tag do you have an action set up for `get` info?

Comment: Yes I have a rest api. I will add my action now.....

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy fix but it will take a few steps:

1. Set up an **action**
2. Set up your **reducer**
3. Fetch and Render data in component

**Creating the Action**

The first thing, you need to set up an action for getting data based on a `VIN`. It looks like you have that with your `tagformsubmit` function. I would make a few adjustments here.

You should include a catch so you know if something went wrong, change your function `param` to include dispatch, add a type and a payload to your dispatch, and fix the string literal in your api address. Seems like a lot but its a quick fix.

Update your current code from this:

```
export function tagformsubmit(data){
return(dispatch) =>{
    axios.get(`http://***`+data)
    .then((response) => {
        dispatch(taglocationsFetchDataSuccess);

    })
  };
}
```

to this here:

```
//Get Tag Form Submit
export const getTagFormSubmit = vin => dispatch => {
  dispatch(loadingFunctionPossibly()); //optional
  axios
    .get(`/api/path/for/route/${vin}`) //notice the ${} here, that is how you use variable here
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_TAG_FORM_TYPE,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_TAG_FORM_TYPE,
        payload: null
      })
    );
};
```

**Creating the Reducer**

Not sure if you have already created your reducer. If you have you can ignore this. Creating your reducer is also pretty simple. First you want to define your initial state then export your function.

Example

```
const initialState = {
  tags: [],
  tag: {},
  loading: false
};

export default (state=initialState, action) => {
    if(action.type === GET_TAG_FORM_TYPE){
        return {
          ...state, 
          tags: action.payload,
          loading: false //optional
        }
     }
     if(action.type === GET_TAG_TYPE){
        return {
          ...state, 
          tag: action.payload,
        }
     }
}
```

Now that you have your **action** and **reducer** let's set up your component.

**Component**

I'm going to assume you know all of the necessary imports. At the bottom of your component, you want to define your proptypes.

```
TaglocaByVIN.propTypes = {
  getTagFormSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  tag: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

`mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  tag: state.tag
});
```

`connect` to component:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getTagFormSubmit })(TaglocaByVIN);
```

Update your submit to both pass data to your function and get the data that is returned.

```
handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const { searchvin } = this.state;

this.props.getTagFormSubmit(searchvin); 

 const { tags } = this.props; 
 tags.map(tag => {
   //do something with that tag
}
```

Putting that all together your component should look like this (not including imports):

```
class TaglocaByVIN extends Component {
  state = {
    searchvin: ""
  };

  handleFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { searchvin } = this.state;

    this.props.getTagFormSubmit(searchvin);

    const { tags } = this.props.tag;
    if(tags === null){ 
       //do nothing
    } else{
       tags.map(tag => {
      //do something with that tag
     });
  };
}
  changeText = e => {
    this.setState({
      searchvin: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
          <label>Please provide the last 8 characters of VIN: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="searchvin"
            value={this.state.searchvin}
            onChange={this.changeText}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TaglocaByVIN.propTypes = {
  getTagFormSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  tag: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  tag: state.tag
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getTagFormSubmit }
)(TaglocaByVIN);
```

That should be it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'm coming with this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: getTags is not defined.  What is getTags??? @BensSteves

Comment: Ok great.  I updated that.  The constant, tags, is not being updated with the list.  I added "console.log(tags)" and it is an empty array.  How do I get the contents from the database into an array or simply displayed on the page?

Comment: I still can not access the taglocations from "this.props.getTagFormSubmit(searchvin)". How do I access taglocations?? Need help!!

Comment: what value does your getTagFormSubmit return? In the source I provided I just put `this.props.getTagFormSubmit(searchvin)` but if that method has a value that it returns you have to set that equal to variable like this `const tagLocations = this.props.getTagFormSubmit(searchvin). Log that variable to the console and see if you get anything.

Comment: It is undefined. Is my reducer correct?  Adding to code above now.........

Comment: Still undefined but its hitting my database....its like its not returning the response/data for some reason.

Comment: I hit the api directly and the data displayed......something is missing...not sure what??

Comment: This is how it looks: [{"id":76,"rfidtag":"sdgasdgasdgasdgasdgasdg","readername":null,"zone":null,"zonedate":"2018-11-07T15:51:44.000+0000","taggingsource":"webapp","vineight":"65417845"},{"id":78,"rfidtag":"sdgasdgasdgasdgasdgasdg","readername":null,"zone":"test location","zonedate":"2018-11-07T16:19:45.000+0000","taggingsource":"webapp","vineight":"65417845"},

Comment: I got the items to display but I still can not see them when I console.log(taglocations).  Why is this?

Comment: After I set taglocations equal to this.props, I do "console.log(taglocations)".  It prints out undefined.

Comment: Now taglocations does not display on the page.

Comment: It doesn't seem as though taglocations is updating when I submit the form.....could it be the mapstatetoprops???

Comment: See my updated answer. change `PropTypes.array` to `PropTypes.object` and use tag singular as the object...hope that makes sense

Comment: Gm! @Bens Steves I changed to object but nothing has changed.  I checked my action and reducer and they both are returning the correct info for taglocation......

Comment: When I check the state of taglocations, it has the array.  So how do I update the props with taglocations????